# How do boolean predicates work in Elasticsearch query string syntax

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a question regarding the ES query string syntax. I am searching logstash log-entries containg xml documents and I'd like to search for documents containg certain XML attributes with certain values. When searching for:

`id: foobar AND attrName=SomeValue`

In my data set this query finds lets say 100 documents

When searching for:

`id: foobar AND attrName SomeValue`

I get less documents. Why is that, when according to the query_string docs the default operator is OR.

When I escape the " character and query like this I get the correct results:
`id: foobar AND attrName=\"SomeValue\"`

I'm running the query using the following json:

```
{
  "sort": [
    "@timestamp"
  ],
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "mySearchText"
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "_id"
  ],
  "size": 100
}
```

Any tips on how to search in XML documents containing only elements and attributes but no text nodes.

Edit #1: I just stumpbled upon another thing I don't understand. Why are these queries different:

```
a AND b OR c
```

is different than:

```
a AND (b OR c)
```

Any tips on how these queries are evaluated?

Edit #2: Okay I think I nailed down what behaviour is confusing me.
When my query string looks like this:

`id: foo AND attrName=\"SomeValue\" AND field2:bar`

I get all documents where: 
- id=foo 
- field2=bar
- contain the text attrName AND the text SomeValue

When I change my query to (added parentheses):
`id: foo AND (attrName=\"SomeValue\") AND field2:bar`
I get all documents where: 
- id=foo 
- field2=bar
- contain the text attrName OR the text SomeValue

Why is (attrName=\"SomeValue\") evaluated as attrName OR SomeValue, whereas without parentheses it is attrName AND SomeValue?

Comment: `a AND b OR c` is equivalent to `(a AND b) OR c`, i.e. in boolean algebra, `AND` has higher precedence over `OR`

Comment: Can you show a sample document you have?

Comment: @Val thanks for your answer any hint on edit #2?